# formatted moment doesn't match with lodash isEqual

Tags: momentjs, lodash, angular2-forms

```
foo = moment();
bar = foo.clone();
_.isEqual(foo, bar); //true
foo.format();
_.isEqual(foo, bar); //false
```

Is anybody know a workaround to make them equal after formatting ??

Edit-- I just care about the dates on those variable

Answer (score 0):

When you call moment() without any parameters it returns a Moment object

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Oct 11 2017 00:51:25), …}
```

but when you use moment().format() it returns a string

`2017-10-11T00:51:29+08:00`

so how can they be equal?

Comment: Yes. You are right. But I just care if  both those variable has the same date or not.

Comment: _.isEqual(moment(foo.format()), moment(bar.format())) should work. But I am looking for a more tidier solution.

Comment: how about trying moment()._d?

Comment: @Jay do **not** use `_d` and other properties prefixed with `_` as stated in the [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) guide.

Comment: Well then that sums up the question, it is clearly said there to use moment().format() and other string methods